# Pure functions optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

A [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) is a function whose return value is the same for the same arguments and that doesn't have any side effects.

Does CPython recognize that the return value will be the same and make an optimization calling the function only once? If not, do other python interpreters do it?

Below I wrote an example using `os.path.join`, assuming it's a pure function (I don't actually know its implementation), but the question extends to all pure functions.

```
dirpath = "C:\\Users"
dirname = "Username"

mylist = [["another\\directory", 6], ["C:\\Users\\Username", 8], ["foo\\bar", 3]]

count = 0

for pair in mylist:
    if os.path.join(dirpath, dirname) == pair[0]:
        count = pair[1]
```

`dirpath` and `dirname` aren't getting modified inside the for loop. Given the same input, `os.path.join` always have the same return value.

Comment: When you say "the python interpreter", which implementation of Python are you referring to ? Cpython ? PyPy ? Jython ? IronPython ? Because the loop optimizations that you are referring to are implementation-specific.

Comment: I don't think this is optimized anywhere. If you want to cache results, you have to do it yourself, e.g. with decorators.

Comment: To expand a bit on what @Erich wrote; the technique to store the results is often called memoization. There are some tutorials available on how to do it, e.g. here: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

Comment: @RishiDev I meant the "standard" one, I'm not sure how it is called. The one that I can download from python.org and then run using "python" from cmd in Windows.

Comment: If you tell me the correct name I would be glad to specify it in the question.

Comment: Also, in the particular example you provided, you can just move the `os.path.join(...)` out of the loop.That is normally something to start with.

Comment: @untitled The standard one in this case is called "Cpython" :) You can add that to the question, as it is quite relevant to the question.

Comment: ``os.path.join`` isn't a pure function. In fact, most functions in Python aren't pure. Since builtins, globals and closures are mutable, any function depending on them is not pure. In addition, it is well-defined to swap the code of a function at runtime. Only compiled builtins *can* be pure, but they are by definition not evaluated by the interpreter.

Comment: As @JohanL mentioned, what you are trying to do is memoization. You can use decorator 'lru_cache' from 'functools' module where you are able to specify number of different parameters sets for which result should be stored. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard python implementation does almost no optimization of user code.

However you can use the [lru cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator on pure functions to get the functionality that you want.

```
from functools import lru_cache

def fib(n):
    """
    Calculate the n'th fibanaci number
    With O(N^2) <quadratic> runtime
    """
    if n < 2: return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

@lru_cache
def fib2(n):
    """
    Calculate the n'th fibanaci number
    With O(N) <linear> runtime
    """
    if n < 2: return n
    return fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, Python does not have pure functions. It is well-defined to modify the meaning of a function at any time.

```
>>> def add(a, b): return a + b
>>> def sub(a, b): return a - b
>>> add(10, 5)
15
>>> add.__code__ = sub.__code__
>>> add(10, 5)
5
```

In addition, it is possible to change the `builtins`, `globals` and closures that a function accesses.

The reference implementation CPython makes no optimisations based on the purity of functions.

The implementation PyPy uses a tracing JIT which is [capable of pure optimisations](https://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jit/optimizer.html#pure-optimization). Note that this applies to low-level operations (not necessarily entire functions) and only in often-used code.